# Can a logical transformation rule be applied when nested within a formula?

Tags: propositional-calculus

As an example, let's take the double negation elimination rule
$$\neg \neg p\vdash p\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ p\vdash\neg \neg p$$

With this, we know that if $p$ is true, then $\neg\neg p$ is true, and vice versa. Now suppose we're given the formula $\phi(p)$, of which we are unaware if either of $p$ or $\phi(p)$ are true. By the double negation elimination rule, do we know if $\phi(p)$ is an equivalent statement to $\phi(\neg\neg p)$? That is to say, can we apply the transformation rule to $p$, even if it's nested within $\phi$?

In other words, does the transformation rule by itself allow us interchange any occurrence of $p$ with $\neg\neg p\ $, or can it only be applied when $p$ is on its own?

Comment: Yes, logically equivalent expressions can be freely substituted with each other in any part of a formula. (as long as we don't do something silly like use a variable name that's already being used somewhere else)

Comment: @GregMartin, Great. Is the ability to do so inherent of the definition of '$\vdash$', or is substitution a separate rule?

Comment: @Graviton It can be proved by induction on complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true and can be proved by induction on formula complexity. Specifically, the key point is that the connectives in classical propositional logic are **truth functionals** in the following sense:

> For each connective $\mathfrak{C}(x_1,...,x_n)$ we have $$\{y_1\leftrightarrow x_1, ..., y_n\leftrightarrow x_n\}\vdash \mathfrak{C}(x_1,...,x_n)\leftrightarrow\mathfrak{C}(y_1,...,y_n).$$

Together with the deduction theorem (which tells us that $\varphi\dashv\vdash\psi$ iff $\vdash\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$) and some induction on complexity, this gives the desired result. Note that both truth functionality in the above sense and the deduction theorem are nontrivial properties of a logic; that said, in my (limited) experience in algebraic logic we do tend to restrict attention to logics with the relevant substitutability property.